# ¿Por qué al introducir los datos correctamente salta el else directamente sin pasar por el primer if de este código Javascript?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, bucles, switch

En este código, al introducir el usuario y la clave de manera correcta, no entiendo por qué salta directo al else del segundo if con el mensaje "usuario o contraseña incorrecto"... me pregunté si escogí erróneamente el tipo de ciclo para este ejercicio y debía hacerse es con un while o un do... while e incluso si está bien el switch

```js
let a = 0

let usuario = ""
let clave = ""
let correcto = false

for ( a=0 ; a<2 ; a++){

    usuario = prompt('ingrese nombre').toLowerCase

    clave = prompt('ingrese clave')

    correcto = false

    switch (usuario){

        case "ana":
            if(clave=="gaviota"){
                correcto=true
            } 
            break

        case "jose":
            if(clave=="cocodrilo"){
                correcto=true
            }
            break
    }

if (correcto ==true){
    alert(" Bienvenido " + usuario)
    break
    }
    else{
        alert("usuario o contraseña incorrecto")
    }
}

if (a == 3)

alert("Sesión bloqueada")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primera, falta `;` al final de todas las declaraciones.
En segunda, en la parte del código que dice:

```js
usuario = prompt("Ingrese nombre").toLowerCase
```

Faltan los caracteres `()` al final de `toLowerCase`.

Comment: El `;` es irrelevante en `js` y es cuestión de gustos ponerlo o no, pero +1 por lo de los paréntesis, esa es la verdadera causa del error.